# Parse logOut disappeared Facebook button from login screen

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

In iOS as expected, when I press on the log out button the user is logged out and the log in screen is moved to the front.  This is accomplished with the following code:

```
- (IBAction)logOutBtnPressed:(id)sender {

    [PFUser logOut];

    logInViewController = [[LogInViewController alloc] init];

    [self presentViewController:logInViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

The problem is that in the login screen (that comes to front), the Facebook button disappears.
If I press on the x (exit) button in the log in screen then the log in screen is refreshed and the Facebook button shows again.

Does anybody know why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: What does the parsing tag have to do with this?

Comment: you right, my mistake. i meant parse.com

Comment: hi, i found how to make it work. i put the line logInViewController = [[LogInViewController alloc] init]; in the viewDidLoad function and use the same instance in the log out function without make a new instance. thats solve the problem

Comment: @OdedDilmoni would you mind sharing your code? I'm having the same issue

Comment: Hi, like i said , i just put:  logInViewController = [[LogInViewController alloc] init]; in the viewDidLoad instead in the button action .